# Spring Cloud Data Flow - Rest Client - Override RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-autoconfiguration

I am using the [Spring Cloud Data Flow Task DSL](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/java-dsl/) to programmatically launch Spring Cloud Data Flow tasks on Kubernetes.

Looking at the source code for [spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client) project, I can see that the [DataFlowClientAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/rest/client/config/DataFlowClientAutoConfiguration.java) class contains a `RestTemplate` instance that is being `Autowired`. I want to pass in my own `RestTemplate` instance primariliy because I want to change the default connection timeout that is being picked up by the `RestTemplate`

To achieve this, I created my own independent spring boot project that uses spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client as a dependency and created a `RestTempalte` bean in my context as shown below :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataFlowRestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataFlowRestClient.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SpringDataFlowRestClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory connectionFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        connectionFactory.setConnectTimeout(300000);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(connectionFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

My assumption was that this would increase the connection timeout for the `RestTemplate` to 5 minute; however, it is clear that my custom `RestTemplate` instance is not being picked up by `DataFlowClientAutoConfiguration` because I can see many requests time out under 30 seconds as I see a 504 Gateway error. (which was the reason why I wanted to increase the timeout in the first place)

I see comments inside [DataFlowTemplate.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/rest/client/DataFlowTemplate.java) that read as follows :

> Please be aware that the created RestTemplate will use the JDK's
> default timeout values. **Consider passing in a custom {@link
> RestTemplate}**

**Question** So how exactly can I **override the `RestTemplate` instance being `Autowired` inside `DataFlowClientAutoConfiguration`??**.

**Note** : I tried using `public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder)` bean method in my configuration but that did not help. I tried setting `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`. I also tried using `@Primary` for my `RestTemplate` bean method. Finally, I tried passing `sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=300000` as an environment variable. Nothing seems to work. I believe I have exhausted all options that I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation. I think this is a design flaw. First of all because it can add side-effects to the primary purposed restTemplate of the app without noticing (i.e, auth). Besides, probably the internal dataFlowOperations() should include all dependencies as args in the signature, so we can bring in the behaviour without replicating all code by doing something like

```
@Bean
public DataFlowOperations dataFlowOperations(){
    return dataFlowClientAutoConfiguration.dataFlowOperations(myCustomRestTemplate(),..);
}
```

Another option would be that all dependencies from the autoconfiguration were injected via constructor, so we could do

```
@Bean 
public DataflowOperations dataflowOperations(){
    return new DataFlowClientAutoConfiguration(restTemplate,...).dataFlowOperations
}
```

I think the only way to achieve our needs right now is either duplicating all DataFlowOperations autconfiguration locally, using reflection (which I am completely stubborn on approve) or either alter the whole arch for the specific dataflowClientRestTemplate to be the @Primary